# Mysql query performance is slow, need help in optimization

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have 4 tables: shipments (200K records), stores (45 records), product_stores (8K records), districts (698 records). The following query takes very long time to excute (12 seconds):

```
SELECT `s`. * , `p`.`productCode` , `p`.`productName` , `st`.`name` AS `storeName` , `d`.`name` AS `districtName`
FROM `shipments` AS `s`
JOIN `product_stores` AS `p` ON s.productStoreId = p.id
JOIN `stores` AS `st` ON s.storeId = st.id
LEFT JOIN `districts` AS `d` ON s.districtId = d.id
WHERE (s.storeId IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 14, 16, 22, 26, 30))
GROUP BY `s`.`id`
ORDER BY `s`.`id` DESC
LIMIT 100
```

EXPLAIN query return the following result:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  st  ALL     PRIMARY     NULL    NULL    NULL    45  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  s   ref     fk_shipments_stores1_idx,fk_shipments_product_stor...   fk_shipments_stores1_idx    4   st.id   482     
1   SIMPLE  p   eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   s.productStoreId    1   
1   SIMPLE  d   eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   s.districtId    1
```

1. I don't know why mysql must Using temporary; Using filesort in this case
2. Why mysql not start select from shipments? then join store. it start select from store then join shipments? I try to run the EXPLAIN and sometime mysql start select from table  product_stores
3. Please help me to optimize the table, indexes...to improve performance.

(I'm using mysql 5.0.95)

This is the table structures:

Comment: Please change your question header to something useful.

Answer (score 1):

your query will be slow enough because your query joining strategy take too much I/O

Let me draft calculate for your query I/O for understanding as follow:

```
 1. JOIN shipments (200K records) and product_stores (8K records) 

         200K x 8 K = 1600K I/O
 2. Then, JOIN to stores (45 records)

         1600K x 45 = 75000K I/O

 3. Then, JOIN to districts (698 records)

         75000K x 698 = 50256000K I/O

 4. Then, Filter the result (by storeId), so need to read the result I/O again

         50256000K + 50256000K = **100512000K I/O (TOTAL I/O)** 

 So, total I/O on memory of your query is 100512000K I/O.
```

---

To improve your query performance, you need to reconsider your query joining plan/strategy

for example:

```
 1. Read shipments (200K records) and Filter storeId  (assume: result is 8 record)

         200K  + 8 = 208K I/O
 2. Then, JOIN to product_stores (8K records)

         208K x 8K = 1664K I/O

 3. Then, JOIN to stores (45 records)

         1664K x 45K = 74880K I/O

 4. Then, finally JOIN to districts (698 records).

         74880K + 698 = **52266240 I/O (TOTAL I/O)** 

 So, total I/O on memory of your query is 52266240  I/O. (greatly reduce I/O then ever)
```

So, you can improve your query performance by above considering way.

I hope it may help you.

Comment: Thankyou very much. I changed the INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN, and now it only 0.003sec: SELECT `s`. * , `ps`.`productCode` , `ps`.`productName` , `st`.`name` AS `storeName` , `d`.`name` AS `shipToDistrictName`
FROM `shipments` AS `s`
LEFT JOIN `product_stores` AS `ps` ON s.productStoreId = ps.id
LEFT JOIN `stores` AS `st` ON (s.storeId = st.id AND st.id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 14, 16, 22, 26, 30))
LEFT JOIN `districts` AS `d` ON s.shipToDistrictId = d.id
GROUP BY `s`.`id`
ORDER BY `s`.`id` DESC
LIMIT 100

Answer (score 0):

I am just trying the solution. Hope this should reduce execution time

```
SELECT `s`. * , `ps`.`productCode` , `ps`.`productName` , `st`.`name` AS `storeName` , `d`.`name` AS `shipToDistrictName`
FROM `shipments` AS `s`
JOIN `product_stores` AS `ps` ON s.productStoreId = ps.id
JOIN `stores` AS `st` ON (s.storeId = st.id AND s.storeId IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 14, 16, 22, 26, 30))
LEFT JOIN `districts` AS `d` ON s.shipToDistrictId = d.id
GROUP BY `s`.`id`
ORDER BY `s`.`id` DESC
LIMIT 100
```

This will restrict number of records to only those having storeId only those that are required and further do joins with reduced number of records, thus reduce the execution time.

Hope it helps...